# How to display ALIAS FIELD in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I don't know how to display alias field in Spring Data JPA.

This is my code

```
@Query("Select b ,count(s) as countSeat  from Bus b join b.seat s where b.idbus = 1  and s.status.idstatus = 1 group by b.idbus ")
    List<Bus>findByID();
```

I write query method to take all field of Entity Bus and Count all of seat with idstatus = 1. I put for count(s) with alias **countSeat**

Everything working, and I have a result like this

```
[[{"idbus":1,
   "driver":"Phan Viet Ha",
   "license":"61X-TN45",
   "route": {"idroute":2,"place":"Route 2 : Quan 6 - FSoft","price":65}, 
   "image":"https://www.sayingtruth.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/bus-donated-at-kotputli-rajasthan.jpg"},
     4]]
```

You can see value of count function is 4 but It's not display alias countSeat.
How can i fix that

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "display"? You have to think about which Java Type your result set has. Looking at your query, you are not selecting a `Bus` only. You select `Bus` and another field. So the result will be a `Tuple`, where field 0 is a `Bus` and field 1 is an integer. Both of those names are not named! Just the fields **inside** `Bus` are named.

So you can either create a DTO/Projection type and create it with a [constructor expression in your query](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), or you just use the [Tuple](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html).

But the snippet you showed in the end, it's not clear what that is. Is that the serialized JSON of your result? In that case, the simplest solution would be the DTO/projection, so you can name the field.
Alternatively, you could build the JSON by hand, fetching the `aliasName` for the field. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/baxtheman/44fd1601380d415eeec53d9e6d5587dc) (not tested by me).